# Listbox not removing values in c# GUI

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, user-interface, listbox

The user basically enters a number of hex values into a textbox separated by commas eg. AA,1B,FF. These are then displayed in a listbox box. if the number of hex values in the textbox exceeds the size to transfer defined by the user, the listbox only displays the this number of values or if the size to transfer is bigger that adds zero values to the listbox.

this works fine until you enter a value with a zero in front of it such as AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,0F, if sizeToTransfer = 2, the listbox should display 0xAA and 0xBB. but instead it only removes the 0F value?

I'm pretty new to programming so it may be something obvious I'm missing any help would be appreciated.

```
        private void WriteSPI1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        string hexstring = textbox1.Text;

        HexValues.Items.Clear();   

        string[] hexarray = hexstring.Split((",\r\n".ToCharArray()), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        byte[] hexbytes = new byte[hexarray.Length]; 

        uint num = Convert.ToUInt32(hexarray.Length);

                    for (int j = 0; j < hexarray.Length; j++)
                    {
                        hexbytes[j] = Convert.ToByte(hexarray[j], 16);
                        Hexlist.Add(hexbytes[j]);
                        writebuff = Hexlist.ToArray();
                        x =  writebuff[j].ToString("X2");
                        HexValues.Items.Add("0x" + x); 
                    }

                    if (hexarray.Length > sizeToTransfer)
                    {
                        diff = num - sizeToTransfer;

                        for (i = 0; i < diff+1; i++)
                        {
                            HexValues.Items.Remove("0x" + x);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        diff = sizeToTransfer - num;

                        for (i = 0; i < diff; i++)
                        {
                            HexValues.Items.Add("0x00");
                        }
                    }
         }
```

Comment: What is the type of `HexValues`?

Comment: the way your logic is set up it removes the 0x values if the length of the array is bigger than what you want to transfer. You are missing a for loop going through the Byte array and then displaying the Bytes you want to show

Comment: HexValues is the listbox name

Comment: 0x is just a string added in front of the hex value input by the user eg 0xAA

Comment: I don't understand your logic: if *sizeToTransfer = 2, the listbox should display 0xAA and 0xBB*... surely the length of 0xAA and 0xBB is 4?

Comment: One byte is 2 hexidecimal characters

Comment: AA = 10101010 = 1 byte

Comment: thanks @wankr  that was it, was just going the wrong way about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CHANGE**

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeToTransfer; j++)
{
    hexbytes[j] = Convert.ToByte(hexarray[j], 16);
    Hexlist.Add(hexbytes[j]);
    writebuff = Hexlist.ToArray();
    x =  writebuff[j].ToString("X2");
    HexValues.Items.Add("0x" + x); 
}
```

**WITH**

```
for (int j = 0; j < hexarray.Length; j++)
{
    hexbytes[j] = Convert.ToByte(hexarray[j], 16);
    Hexlist.Add(hexbytes[j]);
    writebuff = Hexlist.ToArray();
    x =  writebuff[j].ToString("X2");
    HexValues.Items.Add("0x" + x); 
}
```

**and remove the if stantment that follow**